# how to ensure the mutex shared by each thread averagely

Tags: mutex

I tried to find out how to ensure a mutex should be entered into by each thread (POSIX thread in Linux) averagely.

In my program, there is a global queue and it has own mutex lock. A couple of writing threads write element into queue one at a time, and a single reading thread reads out a group of elements from the queue every time. The result is that the size of queue always grows large than the limitation.

so my question is how to ensure that the mutex should be accessed by every thread averagely. Any comments will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about resource starvation? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_starvation

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the scenario of two writer threads, one reader thread and a common buffering queue with some buffer limit.

There are couple of ways doing this.

1. Create the reader thread with higher priority then writer threads. So every time when the lock will be released by any of the writer thread, it will be acquired by the reader thread immediately if it is waiting in the scheduler queue along-with the second writer thread.
2. Use a global synchronized flag to perform the task in queue, and give a threshold for certain reading and writing conditions (say if my queue count is 10, so if the max count will be achieved, next time I will be able to schedule reader thread only with the help of flag for a certain number of times and then will release the flag to work normally). This will help restricting the queue growing larger then the limit.

Hope you understand both the points.